# Loop through array of arrays and extract data by id

Tags: php

I have an array with an id, date, amount of people that went on the holiday, and the location. I need to extract id, date, price and location it by id on a separate array like this:

```
Array ( 
    0 => '6, 2020-01-01, Four people, United Kingdom, 1200.00',
    1 => '2, 2012-04-12, Three people, Australia. 600.00',
    2 => '6, 2018-08-06, Holiday of two, Canada, 2100.00'
...
)
```

This is my desired output, an array of arrays per id

```
$perPersonId = [
    [
        [0]=>2020-01-01,
        [1]=>6,
        [2]=>1200.00,
    ],
    [
        [0]=>2015-12-31,
        [1]=>6,
        [2]=>2100.00,
    ]
.....
];
```

This is what I have so far

```
function x (array $holidays)
{
    foreach($holidays as $holiday) {
        $holidayPerPerson = array_filter (explode(',', $holiday), function ($h) use ($holiday) {
            // not sure what to do here to group holidays per id
        });
    }
    // return array of holidays per person id
}
```

Comment: `1200.00,2100.00,`, from where they came from in your desired output?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add price in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***1.*** You can apply `foreach()` and using `explode()` inside it.

```
function x (array $holidays)
{
    foreach($holidays as &$holiday) { //passing by reference
        $holiday= explode(', ',$holiday);
    }
    return $holidays;
}
```

Output:- https://3v4l.org/jj6Rt

***2.*** As you said you wanna group by `id's`, do like below:

```
function x (array $holidays)
{
    $finalArray = [];
    foreach($holidays as $holiday) {
        $holidays= explode(', ',$holiday);
        $finalArray[$holidays[0]] = (isset($finalArray[$holidays[0]])) ? array_merge($finalArray[$holidays[0]],$holidays) : $holidays;
    }
    return $finalArray;
}

print_r(x($holidays));
```

Output:- https://3v4l.org/3YWYH